# Battery Icon from xposed

Tags: java, android, xposed

I want to know how can i track battery using an xposed module, remove the existing battery meter, and add my own battery meter dynamically. I have no idea how to begin with this. I saw some source codes, but couldn't understand how they work. Please provide with some examples or basic ideas to get started with (links also would be very helpful)

The following is the layout file in my ROM (CoolUI8):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@id/system_icons" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <com.android.keyguard.AlphaOptimizedLinearLayout android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@id/statusIcons" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <include android:id="@id/msim_hd_voice_on" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginStart="2.0dip" layout="@layout/hd_voice_on" />
    <include android:id="@id/msim_signal_cluster" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginStart="2.0dip" layout="@layout/signal_cluster_view_yulong" />
    <com.android.systemui.BatteryViewGroup android:id="@id/battery_field" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginStart="4.0dip">
        <TextView android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.Text.Style" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@id/battery_level" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/battery_level_padding_end" />
        <FrameLayout android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@id/battery_group" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:id="@id/battery_frame" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/stat_sys_battery_frame" android:scaleType="center" />
            <com.android.systemui.BatteryMeterView android:id="@id/battery" android:layout_width="25.0dip" android:layout_height="12.0dip" />
            <ImageView android:id="@id/battery_charge" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="25.0dip" android:src="@drawable/stat_sys_battery_charge_flag" android:scaleType="center" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </com.android.systemui.BatteryViewGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have been successful in hiding the existing battery meter (hid the whole FrameLayout with the id: battery_group), but i want to add custom battery meter there... Please reply if you have any information related to this topic :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm replacing WhatsApp's blue ticks with black in my xposed module. I think your problem is similar to mine.

I dont know if this will help you or not but it'll help you to get started with xposed.

you can implement this method from IXposedHookInitPackageResources interface

```
@Override
public void handleInitPackageResources(XC_InitPackageResources.InitPackageResourcesParam initPackageResourcesParam) throws Throwable {
    if (!initPackageResourcesParam.packageName.equals("com.whatsapp"))
        return;

    //create the resource instance for your package
    modRes = XModuleResources.createInstance(MODULE_PATH, initPackageResourcesParam.res);

    //example to change xml attribute like dimension
    initPackageResourcesParam.res.setReplacement("com.whatsapp", "dimen", "tab_height", modRes.fwd(R.dimen.tab_height));

    //example to replace icon -- battery icon in your case
    initPackageResourcesParam.res.setReplacement("com.whatsapp", "drawable", "message_got_read_receipt_from_target", modRes.fwd(R.mipmap.ic_black_tick_conv));
    initPackageResourcesParam.res.setReplacement("com.whatsapp", "drawable", "message_got_read_receipt_from_target_onmedia", modRes.fwd(R.mipmap.ic_black_tick_conv));
    initPackageResourcesParam.res.setReplacement("com.whatsapp", "drawable", "msg_status_client_read", modRes.fwd(R.mipmap.ic_black_tick_main));

}
```

you can refer my xposed module code to see some examples of xposed

https://github.com/suraj0208/WhatsappExtensions

and last thing, if this helps you accept it as answer. the tick icon on the left :D